# Crystal Reports - Group By

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to just have Crystal Reports to just list a set of result grouping rows by a field.  The group expert function creates a section for each group, I just want to combine all duplicate rows seamlessly like you would using "GROUP BY"

This is my first time using crystal reports.

Instead of:

```
Client 1
   - payment sum
   - payment sum
Client 2
   - payment sum
   - payment sum
```

I want:

```
 col1   |  col2
----------------------
Client1 | payment sum
Client2 | payment sum
Client3 | payment sum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a running total or a Sum formula to add all the payment sum in the Detail section, then put that sum (or running total) and display it in the Group Header and suppress the Detail section.

Comment: Exactly what I would have suggested as well